# Why does changing my home directory in WSL break my PATH but only in the second window in tmux?

Tags: ubuntu, tmux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pty

A bit ago, I found it necessary to set my home directory to my `One Drive` in WSL.  Thanks to [this post](https://jeremyskinner.co.uk/2018/07/27/sharing-home-directory-between-windows-and-wsl/) I was even able to get my permissions working correctly within WSL (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).

However, when I use `tmux` the second `/bin/sh` pseudoterminal I open gives me an error about the path...but not the first one that opens...

The second one (and all the subsequent ones opened there after) give the following error:

```
-sh: 6: export: Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu16.04onWindows_1604.2019.523.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/Program: bad variable name
```

And that part at the end is clearly part of my `$PATH` variable for `/bin/bash` that is not getting set...(`79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/Program`), also I can't tell but it almost looks like this part could be trying to refer to a `c:/`...(`c:/mnt/c/Program`)

Inside the `/bin/sh` pseudoterminal `echo $HOME` reports `/home/<username>` and in plain old `/bin/bash`, `echo $HOME` reports the path to my OneDrive `/c/mnt/Users/<username>/OneDrive - <company-name>`

In `~/.bash_profile` I've tried commenting out the call to `source ~/.bashrc` but the issue above persists after opening a new WSL window.

I believe this has something to do with the fact that I am using `/bin/sh` rather than `/bin/bash` in my `tmux` session, but overall I don't know what `/bin/sh` calls when starting up; however it seems that it handles it differently than `/bin/bash`.

Note also that I've been unable to find an `/etc/tmux.conf` and that I do not have an override file of `~/.tmux.conf` anywhere, so I'm assuming defaults.

I installed `tmux` before fixing the permissions or changing my home directory, so I don't know if that comes into play here.

I do have `.bashrc` in both `/home/<username>` and in my OneDrive folder's root, but the `PATH` variable settings for both are commented out.

Comment: Quote your variables.

Comment: @muru single or double?  And export?

Comment: Okay I fixed this by setting my shell in tmux to `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh`